# initializing the dynamic array of pointer (in a for loop statement)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

Please help me to fill the dynamic array (for loop)

i need a way to access other members here in the array such as `title`, `grade`, `name` and `age`

I'm getting errors when I'm trying to fill it

i think i should do something like

```
cin >> C[i]. //I don't know what to write here
```

- more background is in the comments

```
Student::Student(string a, int b, int c) : Person(a, b)
{
    /*
       my problem is how to open a dynamic array of Courses.    
       And how to fill them    
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCourses; i++)
    {
        // dynamic array goes here!
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [initializing the dynamic array of pointer (in class)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417378/initializing-the-dynamic-array-of-pointer-in-class)

Comment: @CasperVonB it on hold thats why i posted a new one with some changes in the post so u guys can be able to help me

Comment: `this problem is solved and removed thanks again!!! please admins remove this post` Um, no... SO is not a personal helpdesk. It is a repository of questions and questions are supposed to help _other_ people in the future. Y'know, _other_ people? So why would anyone delete your question just because _you_ don't need it any more?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Im new here so i did copy the whole code, i just won't anyone get my code, next time ill post only the problem not the whole code, so sorry!

Comment: @Excalibur: The moment you posted it here you agreed to license it under the terms of [CC by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/); you do not have the legal right to enforce its removal from this website. Please take a moment to read through the Help Centre and learn all about what Stack Overflow is. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to declare new variables and input them by user like

```
if (cin >> title >> grade >> name >> age)
{
    // use values
} else
{
    // handle errors
}
```

and then in the for loop

```
C[i] = new Course(title, grade, ... );
```

Comment: [members] are grade,title,name,age

Comment: Fair enough. Looks to make some sense now :) Consider handling errors too.